# Совет по разработке приложения (типо AppLock) на Android

Tags: java, android

для учёбы понадобилось разработать приложение, которое ограничивает доступ к другим приложениям на устройстве. Основная проблема в том, что я не могу понять как сделать так, что бы данное приложение запускалось при запуске какого-то из приложений и показывало поле для ввода пин-кода, например. Может быть есть какие-то материалы на эту тему, найти их оказалось тоже трудно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](http://codeworld55.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-create-android-app-lock.html) простой вариант того что вам нужно. А вообще, можете поискать запросом `app lock example in android`, там есть и примеры и готовые библиотеки.